Asset validation failed while distributing app to TestFlight in React Native
I got this error while my app to TestFlight Internal only.
Asset validation failed:
Invalid Signature. Code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s). The file at path "Leasing.app/Frameworks/ hermes.framework/hermes" is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing.
Last time I faced this kind of error (Asset validation failed), I changed the app icon, which was working fine. but for now, i don't know what is the actual problem.

Several things to try: 1. Clean All and re-archive. 2. Verify you have choose "Embed&Sign" option in Frameworks,Libraries, and Embeded Content section. 3. Use codesign -dvvv to verify the framework's binary's signature, it should not be signed in the project. 4. Verify you have set the correct signing certificate.
